# c++ GUI programming with QT4 source code

Tags: qt

Is examples code of c++ GUI programming with QT4 source code available to download ? Can anybody provide a link for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [this page](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0132354160) I found the Windows and Linux Version of the code under the tab *Downloads*.

But I'm not sure if this is totally legal due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Qt 4.7: Qt Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/all-examples.html) is what you want. (The source code of the `Qt` framework itself is available in the standard `Qt` dowload package.)